# Unit test of code using Hibernate Validator fails with Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'

Tags: java, unit-testing, hibernate-validator

I'm attempting to use Hibernate Validator in an API gateway framework.  The code eventually runs in Karaf, but I'm trying to get a unit test (not a PAX test) working first.  I'll be using Mockito for mocking, but I don't think that's an issue yet.

I'm using "hibernate-validator" and "hibernate-validator-annotation-processor", version 5.4.1.Final.

When I run the test, I get the following:

```
HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead
```

From other occurrences of this, I concluded that I have to add "org.glassfish:javax.el:3.0.0".  Unfortunately, this had no effect.  Exact same exception.

**Update**:

Some advice I've seen said to REMOVE the "javax.el-api" artifact.  I found this referenced in one POM, so I commented it out.  I also noticed that the "cdi-api" artifact appears to pull it in transitively, so I also commented that out.

Unfortunately, "mvn dependency:tree" still shows the 2.2.5 version of "javax.el-api" showing up, along with the 3.0.0 version of the glassfish "javax.el" artifact.

How do I get past this?

**Update**:

I've now updated my dependencies so that I have only "javax.el", version 3.0.1-b08, no "api" variant, but I'm still getting the error.

Here's my current dependency tree:

```
[INFO] mygroupid:usl-fraudcheck-impl:bundle:2.5.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- mygroupid:usl-csi-jaxb-base:jar:2.5.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- mygroupid:usl-shared:jar:2.5.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlbeans:jar:2.5.0_1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xstream:jar:1.4.9_1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1_2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.javax.mail:jar:1.4.1_5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-httpclient:jar:3.1_7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-codec:jar:1.3_5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-io:jar:1.4_3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.ejb:javax.ejb-api:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.jms:javax.jms-api:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- mygroupid.csi:csi88:jar:88.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- mygroupid.csi:csi213:jar:213.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.xml.rpc:com.springsource.javax.xml.rpc:jar:1.1.0.v20110517:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.interceptor:javax.interceptor-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.javax-inject:jar:1_2:compile
[INFO] |  +- mygroupid:usl-base:jar:2.5.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.axis:axis:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.woden:woden-api:jar:1.0M9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:com.springsource.org.apache.commons.net:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.woden:woden-impl-dom:jar:1.0M9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.woden:woden-impl-commons:jar:1.0M9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.ws.commons.schema:XmlSchema:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-osgi:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-osgi:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-cache:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:fluent-hc:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2_5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.axiom:com.springsource.org.apache.axiom:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.axiom-impl:jar:1.2.13_1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.james:apache-mime4j-core:jar:0.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-activation_1.1_spec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.axis:com.springsource.org.apache.axis:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:com.springsource.org.apache.commons.httpclient:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.apache.commons:com.springsource.org.apache.commons.codec:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:com.springsource.org.apache.commons.discovery:jar:0.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.jms:com.springsource.javax.jms:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- mygroupid.csi:csi-app:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- mygroupid.csi:csi97:jar:97.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- mygroupid.csi:csi104:jar:104.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- mygroupid.csi:csi106:jar:106.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- mygroupid.csi:csi112:jar:112.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- mygroupid.csi:csi109:jar:109.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- mygroupid.csi:csi217:jar:217.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- mygroupid.csi:csi116:jar:116:compile
[INFO] |  +- mygroupid.csi.icas:csi116:jar:200.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- mygroupid.csi.unifiedservices:csi116:jar:212.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- mygroupid.csi.paom:csi112:jar:205.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- mygroupid.csi.oneviewaddresslocationsystem:csi116:jar:203.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- mygroupid.csi.orderandsubscriptionmanagementmobility:csi116:jar:206.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- mygroupid.csi:csi121:jar:121:compile
[INFO] |  \- mygroupid.csi.unifiedservices:csi121:jar:216.0:compile
[INFO] +- mygroupid:usl-fraudcheck-api:jar:2.5.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- mygroupid:usl-metrics:jar:2.5.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     +- mygroupid.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- mygroupid.oracle:oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver:jar:12.1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.2-GA:compile
[INFO] +- mygroupid.xmlsoap:xmlsoap:jar:11.0:compile
[INFO] +- mygroupid:usl-csi-jaxb-base:test-jar:tests:2.5.0-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator-annotation-processor:jar:5.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.1-b08:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:provided
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.cobertura:cobertura:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1-beta-8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xom:xom:jar:1.0b3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:jar:0.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api-2.5:jar:6.1.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun:tools:jar:0:system
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.cobertura:cobertura-runtime:pom:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- urbanophile:java-getopt:jar:1.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-file:jar:1.0-beta-2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-lightweight:jar:1.0-beta-2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-shared:jar:1.0-beta-2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     \- jtidy:jtidy:jar:4aug2000r7-dev:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-beta-2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ssh-external:jar:1.0-beta-2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ssh-common:jar:1.0-beta-2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ssh:jar:1.0-beta-2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.27:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.0.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-core:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-i18n:jar:1.0-beta-7:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-decoration-model:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-apt:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-fml:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-xdoc:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-module-xhtml:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-invoker:jar:2.0.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.osgi:org.osgi.core:jar:5.0.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.osgi:org.osgi.compendium:jar:5.0.0:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.6.6:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:1.6.6:test
[INFO] |     +- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.6.6:test
[INFO] |     \- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.6.6:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.6.6:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito-common:jar:1.6.6:test
[INFO] |     \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.6.6:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.aries.blueprint:org.apache.aries.blueprint.annotation.api:jar:1.0.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.ops4j.pax.exam:pax-exam-junit4:jar:4.9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.ops4j.pax.exam:pax-exam-spi:jar:4.9.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.ops4j.pax.tinybundles:tinybundles:jar:2.1.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- biz.aQute.bnd:bndlib:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.ops4j.base:ops4j-base-lang:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] +- org.ops4j.pax.exam:pax-exam-container-karaf:jar:4.9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.ops4j.pax.exam:pax-exam-container-remote:jar:4.9.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ops4j.pax.exam:pax-exam-container-rbc-client:jar:4.9.1:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.ops4j.pax.exam:pax-exam-container-rbc:jar:4.9.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ops4j.pax.swissbox:pax-swissbox-core:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.ops4j.pax.swissbox:pax-swissbox-lifecycle:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.ops4j.base:ops4j-base-net:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.ops4j.pax.swissbox:pax-swissbox-framework:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ops4j.pax.swissbox:pax-swissbox-tracker:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ops4j.base:ops4j-base-exec:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ops4j.base:ops4j-base-io:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.ops4j.base:ops4j-base-monitors:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.ops4j.base:ops4j-base-spi:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.karaf:apache-karaf:zip:4.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.karaf.features:framework:kar:4.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.karaf.features:base:jar:4.0.7:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.karaf:org.apache.karaf.main:jar:4.0.7:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.karaf:org.apache.karaf.util:jar:4.0.7:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.utils:jar:1.8.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.2.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:4.2.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.karaf:org.apache.karaf.exception:jar:4.0.7:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.karaf:org.apache.karaf.client:jar:4.0.7:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.sshd:sshd-core:jar:0.14.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.karaf.jaas:org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot:jar:4.0.7:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.karaf.diagnostic:org.apache.karaf.diagnostic.boot:jar:4.0.7:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.osgi:jar:3.10.101.v20150820-1432:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.framework:jar:5.4.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- jline:jline:jar:2.14.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jledit:core:jar:0.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ops4j.pax.logging:pax-logging-api:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ops4j.pax.logging:pax-logging-service:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ops4j.pax.url:pax-url-aether:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.karaf.features:org.apache.karaf.features.core:jar:4.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.karaf.features:framework:xml:features:4.0.7:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.karaf.features:standard:xml:features:4.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.karaf.features:spring:xml:features:4.0.7:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.karaf.features:enterprise:xml:features:4.0.7:runtime
[INFO] +- org.ops4j.pax.exam:pax-exam:jar:4.9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.ops4j.base:ops4j-base-store:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.ops4j.base:ops4j-base-util-property:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.17.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-blueprint:jar:2.17.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-core-xml:jar:2.17.0:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-core-osgi:jar:2.17.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-jms:jar:2.17.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-spring:jar:2.17.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-jaxb:jar:2.17.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-test:jar:2.17.0:test
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:provided
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-test-blueprint:jar:2.13.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.aries.blueprint:org.apache.aries.blueprint:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.aries:org.apache.aries.util:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.aries.proxy:org.apache.aries.proxy.impl:jar:1.0.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.aries.proxy:org.apache.aries.proxy.api:jar:1.0.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.googlecode.pojosr:de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework:jar:0.2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.ops4j.pax.swissbox:pax-swissbox-tinybundles:jar:1.3.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.ops4j.pax.swissbox:pax-swissbox-bnd:jar:1.3.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- biz.aQute:bndlib:jar:0.0.357:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.configadmin:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:jar:3.2.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-jackson:jar:2.17.0:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.7.2:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-jsonpath:jar:2.17.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-jolt:jar:2.17.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-quartz2:jar:2.17.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.2.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.5.2:provided
[INFO] |     \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.11:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-hazelcast:jar:2.17.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.hazelcast:hazelcast:jar:3.6.2:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.hazelcast:hazelcast-client:jar:3.6.2:provided
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.0.0:provided
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.3:provided
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.3:provided
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.3:provided
[INFO] +- com.bazaarvoice.jolt:jolt-core:jar:0.0.16:provided
[INFO] |  \- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:provided
[INFO] +- com.bazaarvoice.jolt:json-utils:jar:0.0.16:provided
[INFO] +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.1.1:provided
[INFO] +- net.minidev:asm:jar:1.0.2:provided
[INFO] |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:provided
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.0:provided
[INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit4:jar:2.19.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:2.19.1:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.8:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-client:jar:3.1.8:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.1.8:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:3.1.8:provided
[INFO] |     \- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] +- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:jar:runtime:0.7.8:test
[INFO] \- org.eclipse.jdt:org.eclipse.jdt.annotation:jar:2.1.0:compile
```

The following is an excerpt from the output of "mvn install" in the module, when it's running the unit test:

```
Running package.usl.fraudcheck.impl.InquireCPNIContactInformationProcessorTest
[org.jboss.logging] : Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4j2LoggerProvider Ignored FQCN: org.jboss.logging.Logger
[org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] : HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.4.1.Final Ignored FQCN: org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.logging.Log_$logger
[org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver] : Cannot find javax.persistence.Persistence on classpath. Assuming non JPA 2 environment. All properties will per default be traversable. Ignored FQCN: org.jboss.logging.DelegatingBasicLogger
[org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationXmlParser] : Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml for XML based Validator configuration. Ignored FQCN: org.jboss.logging.DelegatingBasicLogger
[org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ResourceLoaderHelper] : Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via TCCL Ignored FQCN: org.jboss.logging.DelegatingBasicLogger
[org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ResourceLoaderHelper] : Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via Hibernate Validator's class loader Ignored FQCN: org.jboss.logging.DelegatingBasicLogger
[org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationXmlParser] : No META-INF/validation.xml found. Using annotation based configuration only. Ignored FQCN: org.jboss.logging.DelegatingBasicLogger
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.67 sec <<< FAILURE! - in package.usl.fraudcheck.impl.InquireCPNIContactInformationProcessorTest
testValidate(package.usl.fraudcheck.impl.InquireCPNIContactInformationProcessorTest)  Time elapsed: 0.219 sec  <<< ERROR!
javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead
    at package.usl.fraudcheck.impl.InquireCPNIContactInformationProcessorTest.testValidate(InquireCPNIContactInformationProcessorTest.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ExpressionFactory
    at package.usl.fraudcheck.impl.InquireCPNIContactInformationProcessorTest.testValidate(InquireCPNIContactInformationProcessorTest.java:23)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you really need only one version of the el jar. And it should be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1-b08</version>
</dependency>
```

As for the other el jars, you need to exclude them from your dependencies. The dependency tree should help you as you are able to see where they come from.

Just use an exclusion on the dependencies transitively bringing the old el jars and be sure you don't reference it explicitly in your poms and it should work.

The other solution, as mentioned by the error message, is to use a message interpolator not using EL but I wouldn't recommend it as some built-in constraints use EL in their messages and you will probably need it for your own constraints.

Comment: For now, I just updated one dependency with that specific version, and I don't have that artifact orf the "api" variant in the dependency tree, but I still get the error.  I'll update the post with more detail.

Comment: Ah, I think I've fixed it. There was an error message in the build that was missing, saying ".m2\repository\org\glassfish\javax.el\3.0.1-b08\javax.el-3.0.1-b08.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)". I simply removed the "javax.el" directory in the cache and rebuilt, and that resolved it.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same error even after adding a dependency to `org.glassfish:javax.el:3.0.1-b08`. The issue turned out to be transitive dependencies being pulled in that include `javax.el.ExpressionFactory` but have no implementation.

The following command will output *all* the dependencies that include `javax.el.ExpressionFactory`

```
for i in $(mvn dependency:build-classpath | grep '.m2' | tr ':' ' '); do
  jar -tvf $i | grep  'javax/el/ExpressionFactory' && echo -e "\t$i"
done  2> /dev/null
```

I then used `<exclusions>` in my pom.xml to remove the jars that do not match `org.glassfish:javax.el:3.0.1-b08`.

The exclusions *may* end up removing code in the excluded Jars that is needed as well. In my case I had to find a replacement jar that provided an embedded Jetty Server.

Comment: It is always best to include the solution directly rather than posting a link